# WPF GridSplitter not working

Tags: c#, wpf, gridsplitter

I'm unable to get the Gridsplitter to function with the following example code. The grid splitter does not move or resize the surrounding "Top" and "Buttom" grid rows which are set to fill available space:

```
<Grid Width="Auto" Height="Auto">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Grid Grid.Row="0">
        <TextBlock FontSize="55" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" TextWrapping="Wrap">Top</TextBlock>
    </Grid>

    <Grid Grid.Row="1">
        <GridSplitter Height="5" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" ResizeDirection="Rows"/>
    </Grid>

    <Grid Grid.Row="2">
        <TextBlock FontSize="55" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" TextWrapping="Wrap">Bottom</TextBlock>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit:** As Clemens says, your GridSplitter has to be a direct child of the grid that you want to split. You are putting a new Grid into row 1 of the parent grid when you do:

```
<Grid Grid.Row="1">
    <GridSplitter Height="5" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" ResizeDirection="Rows"/>
</Grid>
```

You need to put the splitter directly into the parent grid that you want to split and declare the row in the element tag:

```
<Grid Width="Auto" Height="Auto">
       <Grid.RowDefinitions>
           <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
           <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
           <RowDefinition Height="*"/>

       <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" FontSize="55" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" TextWrapping="Wrap">Top</TextBlock>

       <GridSplitter Grid.Row="1" Height="5" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" ResizeDirection="Rows"/>

       <TextBlock Grid.Row="2" FontSize="55" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" TextWrapping="Wrap">Bottom</TextBlock>
</Grid>
```

Comment: "*not sure why*" - simply because it has to be a direct child of the Grid on which it is supposed to operate.

Comment: Thanks Clemens that makes sense! Removing the Grid Row tags from around the Gridsplitter to make it a direct child works perfectly!

Answer (score 1):

Just remove the Grids that are useless:

```
<Grid Width="Auto" Height="Auto">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <TextBlock FontSize="55" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" TextWrapping="Wrap">Top</TextBlock>

        <GridSplitter Grid.Row="1" Height="5" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" ResizeDirection="Rows"/>

        <TextBlock FontSize="55"  Grid.Row="2" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" TextWrapping="Wrap">Bottom</TextBlock>
</Grid>
```

**EDIT :**

For clarity: the GridSplitter control resizes just elements at its same level in Grid children hierarchy. You can put whatever you want inside the grid, but you have to put the GridSplitter to the same level of the control you want to resize.

You can still do this:

```
<Grid Width="Auto" Height="Auto">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid>
        <TextBlock FontSize="55" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" TextWrapping="Wrap">Top</TextBlock>
    </Grid>

    <GridSplitter Grid.Row="1" Height="5" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" ResizeDirection="Rows"/>

    <Grid Grid.Row="2">
      <TextBlock FontSize="55"  HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" TextWrapping="Wrap">Bottom</TextBlock>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

But the GridSplitter has to be at the same level of the control you want to resize.

Comment: Thanks, this works. Do you know why you need to remove the grid row tag for the Gridsplitter to function?

Also the grid tags may be redundant in my example code, but my actual code has far more elements within each grid row (some with nested grid definitions). Without these tags I find more complex designs become difficult to keep readable/organised.

Comment: The GridSplitter control resizes just element at its same level in Grid children hierarchy. You can put whatever you want inside the grid, but you have to put the GridSplitter to the same level of the control you want to resize.

Comment: Thanks I understand this now, that my Gridsplitter was not a direct child of the grid I was trying to resize!